# script tags not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

i want a sweet-alert popup to show after a database query is successful upon clicking on a buttn. when i put the sweet-alert script tag in the php code i doesnt work

```
<?php 

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ('includes/database.php');

if(isset($_POST['cmptbtn']))
     {

                              $cmpltxt = $_POST['cmpltxt'];
                              $checkbox = $_POST['cmplt'];
                              // $chkb ="";
   $sqlchkb = $conn->query("INSERT INTO complaint (complaint_type, complaint_comm) VALUES ('$checkbox', '$cmpltxt')");

                              // $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO complaint (complaint_comm) VALUES ('$cmpltxt')");

                              }
                              if ($sqlchkb === true){

                                echo "<script type="text/javascript">

                                    document.querySelector('.btnsnd').onclick = function(){
                                    swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                                  };

                                  </script>";

                              }else{

                                echo "sorry try again";


                                }


                             $conn->close();


                       ?>
```

Comment: You need to go learn some absolute syntax basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

you have start and finish echo with `"` and it is not true buecuse in you echo str you can `"` too , try `'` like this :

```
<?php 

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   include ('includes/database.php');

    if(isset($_POST['cmptbtn']))
    {

                          $cmpltxt = $_POST['cmpltxt'];
                          $checkbox = $_POST['cmplt'];
                          // $chkb ="";
    $sqlchkb = $conn->query("INSERT INTO complaint (complaint_type, complaint_comm) VALUES ('$checkbox', '$cmpltxt')");

                          // $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO complaint (complaint_comm) VALUES ('$cmpltxt')");

                          }
                          if ($sqlchkb === true){

                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">

                                document.querySelector(".btnsnd").onclick = function(){
                                swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                              };

                              </script>';

                          }else{ echo "sorry try again"; }


                         $conn->close();


                   ?>
```

i hope it will work.let me know.

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ('includes/database.php');

if(isset($_POST['cmptbtn']))
     {

```
                          $cmpltxt = $_POST['cmpltxt'];
                          $checkbox = $_POST['cmplt'];
                          // $chkb ="";


                          $sqlchkb = $conn->query("INSERT INTO complaint (complaint_type, complaint_comm) VALUES ('$checkbox', '$cmpltxt')");

                          }
                          if ($sqlchkb === true){

                            ?><script type="text/javascript">

                                document.querySelector('.btnsnd').onclick = function abc(){
                                swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
                              };

                              </script><?php

                          }else{

                            echo "sorry try again";


                            }


                         $conn->close();


                   ?>
```

try this

Comment: should you try place function out side and re call it where you want to show popup

Comment: yeah works. thanks a lot. And how do i make the popup stay while the page loads?